# Music Library Capable Player for Windows that is Database Compatible to Banshee

Tags: windows, music, media-player

I am using a multiple OS environment. I have three PCs (2 Laptops and one Mid Tower) all are running Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu Linux. I use Linux for Daily use, but sometimes (Photoshop, Videocutting, other Stuff), I need to use Windows.

I am syncing my Music Library over all my devices and use banshee in the newest version as a main music player with library functionality under ubuntu.

I am now looking for a Player that supports the banshee databases under windows. e.g. I have a folder with the music an I have the banshee db file and I want at least to see the "added at" dates and my playlists The windows player does not need to write the db (but would be cool if it could)

Banshee is available for Windows but does not work correctly. So I am looking for a replacement for that (under Windows)

Comment: I hate that feeling, when my questions get vote ups but I have no answers yet ;-) Merry Christmas everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but just in case:

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html) has the ability to run on multiple platforms (MacOS, Linux, Windows,etc)

- It is free and open source
- It has a "Banshee Import" plugin. Only needs to be switched on.
- It can play local files e.g. mp3, flac
- Music can be organised by playlists, and drag and drop tracks easily. You can also import/export playlists.
- It also has a powerful search facility, and can sort/filter by title, album, artist, year etc. You can see more details on Search [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/searching.html#searching).
- See [here](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html) for a full list of features